# Convert Exponential form of Complex Equation into polar form with Sympy, python

Tags: python, sympy, ode, differential-equations, polar-coordinates

I am trying to solve a differential equation with sympy module in python.
This is what I did

```
from sympy import *


t = sympy.Symbol('t')      
k = sympy.Symbol('k')      
m = sympy.Symbol('m')      
x = sympy.Function('x')(t)     

GDE = Eq(m*x.diff(t, 2) + k*x, 0)

solution = dsolve(GDE, x)
display(solution)
```

[image: This is the solution]

Now, I am trying to get a solution in polar form with both sin, cos and complex term (i) like this picture. In this picture, w_n is sqrt(k/m)

[image: This is what I am trying to get]

I tried

```
solution.rewrite(sin)
```

but it returns an expression with hyperbolic functions .rewrite(cos) also returns an expression with hyperbolic functions.

[image]

I also tried

```
solution.rewrite(sin, cos)
```

but it gives the initial answer.

Is there any way to convert this exponential form of complex form to polar form without hyperbolic functions?

Thank you

Comment: I think the solution of the ODE does not contain sin() or cos(), then it cannot be converted into polar form. In other words, the solution is multiplied by cos(0*t)

Comment: I don't get it, A combination if two real exponential cannot transform into a complex exponential on its own. If you want smt over the complex field you have to specify it with Symbol

Comment: sinh and cosh are just placeholder for a special combination of exponentials => sympy is right

Comment: @ Patricio Loncomilla the syntax should be: Symbol("x*, complex=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your symbols as real or positive etc. Otherwise by default SymPy assumes something like a complex number:

```
In [7]: import sympy

In [8]: from sympy import *
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: t = sympy.Symbol('t', real=True)
   ...: k = sympy.Symbol('k', positive=True)
   ...: m = sympy.Symbol('m', positive=True)
   ...: x = sympy.Function('x', real=True)(t)
   ...: 
   ...: GDE = Eq(m*x.diff(t, 2) + k*x, 0)
```

Then various simplifications will happen automatically:

```
In [9]: sqrt(-k/m)
Out[9]: 
ⅈ⋅√k
────
 √m 

In [10]: exp(t * sqrt(-k/m))
Out[10]: 
 ⅈ⋅√k⋅t
 ──────
   √m  
ℯ      

In [11]: exp(t * sqrt(-k/m)).rewrite(cos)
Out[11]: 
     ⎛√k⋅t⎞      ⎛√k⋅t⎞
ⅈ⋅sin⎜────⎟ + cos⎜────⎟
     ⎝ √m ⎠      ⎝ √m ⎠
```

In fact with the assumptions set `dsolve` will give the `sin`, `cos` form automatically:

```
In [12]: dsolve(GDE)
Out[12]: 
             ⎛√k⋅t⎞         ⎛√k⋅t⎞
x(t) = C₁⋅sin⎜────⎟ + C₂⋅cos⎜────⎟
             ⎝ √m ⎠         ⎝ √m ⎠
```

Without these assumptions set it is still possible to manipulate the expression into the `sin/cos` form but some `force=True` is needed to override the assumptions checking:

```
In [25]: s = solution.rhs; s
Out[25]: 
           _____             _____
          ╱ -k              ╱ -k  
    -t⋅  ╱  ───        t⋅  ╱  ─── 
       ╲╱    m           ╲╱    m  
C₁⋅ℯ             + C₂⋅ℯ           

In [26]: s = expand(s, force=True); s
Out[26]: 
                ___                  ___
               ╱ 1                  ╱ 1 
    -ⅈ⋅√k⋅t⋅  ╱  ─        ⅈ⋅√k⋅t⋅  ╱  ─ 
            ╲╱   m               ╲╱   m 
C₁⋅ℯ                + C₂⋅ℯ              

In [27]: s = s.rewrite(sin); s
Out[27]: 
   ⎛       ⎛         ___⎞      ⎛         ___⎞⎞      ⎛     ⎛         ___⎞      ⎛         ___⎞⎞
   ⎜       ⎜        ╱ 1 ⎟      ⎜        ╱ 1 ⎟⎟      ⎜     ⎜        ╱ 1 ⎟      ⎜        ╱ 1 ⎟⎟
C₁⋅⎜- ⅈ⋅sin⎜√k⋅t⋅  ╱  ─ ⎟ + cos⎜√k⋅t⋅  ╱  ─ ⎟⎟ + C₂⋅⎜ⅈ⋅sin⎜√k⋅t⋅  ╱  ─ ⎟ + cos⎜√k⋅t⋅  ╱  ─ ⎟⎟
   ⎝       ⎝     ╲╱   m ⎠      ⎝     ╲╱   m ⎠⎠      ⎝     ⎝     ╲╱   m ⎠      ⎝     ╲╱   m ⎠⎠

In [28]: s = expand(s).collect(s.atoms(sin, cos)); s
Out[28]: 
             ⎛         ___⎞                     ⎛         ___⎞
             ⎜        ╱ 1 ⎟                     ⎜        ╱ 1 ⎟
(C₁ + C₂)⋅cos⎜√k⋅t⋅  ╱  ─ ⎟ + (-ⅈ⋅C₁ + ⅈ⋅C₂)⋅sin⎜√k⋅t⋅  ╱  ─ ⎟
             ⎝     ╲╱   m ⎠                     ⎝     ╲╱   m ⎠

In [29]: s = powsimp(s, force=True); s
Out[29]: 
             ⎛         ___⎞                     ⎛         ___⎞
             ⎜        ╱ 1 ⎟                     ⎜        ╱ 1 ⎟
(C₁ + C₂)⋅cos⎜√k⋅t⋅  ╱  ─ ⎟ + (-ⅈ⋅C₁ + ⅈ⋅C₂)⋅sin⎜√k⋅t⋅  ╱  ─ ⎟
             ⎝     ╲╱   m ⎠                     ⎝     ╲╱   m ⎠

In [30]: s = powsimp(s, force=True, deep=True); s
Out[30]: 
             ⎛      ___⎞                     ⎛      ___⎞
             ⎜     ╱ k ⎟                     ⎜     ╱ k ⎟
(C₁ + C₂)⋅cos⎜t⋅  ╱  ─ ⎟ + (-ⅈ⋅C₁ + ⅈ⋅C₂)⋅sin⎜t⋅  ╱  ─ ⎟
             ⎝  ╲╱   m ⎠                     ⎝  ╲╱   m ⎠
```